# Python - calling method inside class - behavior varies depending on where call comes from

Tags: python, oop

I'm new to object oriented programming in Python. 
The screenshot shows the problem I am facing - when  the instance method f() is getting called from outside the class, it works, but when called from within another method in the same class, it errors out. why is this happening? How can I fix it?

```py
class C:
    def f1(self):
        print(self.a)
    def g(self):
        f1()

c = C()
c.a = 'aa'
c.f1()
c.g()
```

Output:

```
aa
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-8d929c63c841> in <module>
      8 c.a = 'aa'
      9 c.f1()
---> 10 c.g()

<ipython-input-1-8d929c63c841> in g(self)
      3         print(self.a)
      4     def g(self):
----> 5         f1()
      6 
      7 c = C()

NameError: name 'f1' is not defined
```

Comment: since `f1` is a class method, you need to use `self.f1()` to call it. this means call the function named `f1` on the class instance `self`. when you call `c.g()`, it is looking for a function named `f1` which is not defined, as your error states.

Comment: Got it, thanks khuynh! feeling dumb I missed this

Comment: @khuynh that is not what a class method is

Comment: @anon01, you're correct. it is actually an instance method

Comment: @AadithRamia, a good way to tell if a method is class (aka static) or instance, check if it has the `self` parameter. When you do `object.method()`, `object` is passed in as the first argument (which is usually given the name `self`). On the other hand, a static method would not use a `self` argument, and you would simply use `ClassName.method()`, which will not pass anything as `self`, as there is no object, just the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

Python has very open scope, except when functions or variables are declared within a class. A variable declared within a loop will persist outside the loop, unlike a lot of common languages. However functions and variables within a class will exist within the scope of the class. Therefore if you declare a class like C, with a function inside, it will expect it to be part of the class it is within (thus the need to pass self) and you will need to specify self when calling the function.